# How to configure Micromax 352g USB Modem?

Tags: software-installation, usb-modem

I want the driver software for my Micromax 352g USB modem for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. On Ubuntu 10.04 sakis3g was working well, but it is not working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I have had to delete your answer since you have copied the entire blog here (http://xiidimension.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/running-micromax-352g-modem-on-ubuntu.html) without attribution nor permission from the author.  This is not fair use and therefore is not allowed on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

First edit the `modules` file by running this command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modules
```

That will open a text editor. Add these lines at the bottom of the file:

```
usbserial
option
```

This works for me, hope this will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

Micromax modem detected in Ubuntu 12.04 after following the above mentioned process.

the command `gksu gedit /etc/modules` works and opens a text file there I found `ls` already written at the bottom
 I have just typed:

```
usbserial 
option
```

and closed the text file without saving then after restarting i unpluged the device and plugged then it detected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps described in the following link. It was worked . finally my problem with micromax usb modem got solved.

[Configure Micromax Modem on Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10](http://imacify.com/2012/10/how-to-configure-micromax-3g-modem-on-ubuntu-12-10/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.