# How to Install USB Micromax MMX 354G in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: networking, drivers

How to install *Micromax MMX 354G USB* in Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/151366/how-to-configure-micromax-352g-usb-modem

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 **server** is still supported until April 2015.

Comment: @Takkat my bad I was looking at the EOL list and not the current list and can't seem to find the graph